# Configuring PHPStorm to accept connections from another domain (AJAX)

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm pulling out my hair trying to figure out how best to setup PHP storm to utilize xdebug in the following scenario. I have a laravel application running on domain laravel.com (this is an API in the making) and a website at website.com. The website makes AJAX requests of the laravel application it is here that I want to utilize xdebug the most. I seem to be missing something in the setup as when I browse to the laravel or website urls directly the breakpoints work fantastically. If I use my AJAX login form on the website which hits say laravel.com/login I do not see any breakpoint action on my laravel controller. Do I need to have phpstorm listen to connection on another domain? Is there some sort of proxy setting I need to setup. I seem to be going in circles, any help would be greatly appreciated. Everything is on a Vagrant box by the way.